# In a responsive webpage, how do you get the viewport's visible content in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

Assuming I have a large div holding just text and presented responsively.

Is there a way to get the actual content that is visible on the screen within that div?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this is to use the [jQuery `:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) in combination with the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$("div.your-class:visible").text();
```

Comment: I believe it does not answer the question asked. It would return the whole contents of the div irregardless of what part of it is shown, wouldn't it?

Comment: @zerkms - add a better answer then. The visible selector only selects what's visible in the viewport. It's the easiest way to get this done but unlikely to be the only way. Show the O.P another way if you think of something better.

Comment: Not sure why you're hostile. I just pointed out, that the answer is not what OP asked.

Comment: "The visible selector only selects what's visible in the viewport" --- that's correct, but it deals with the entire elements, whereas OP asked about just *the text* that is shown. It's a crucial difference there.

Comment: The question itself is misleading. OP mentioned that it's presented 'responsively' which gives the impression that the entire div is visible.

Comment: As @zerkms wrote, the visible selector gets the whole content of the div, whereas I'm trying to get only the currently visible part.

Comment: @char when I say presented responsively it just basically means that the presented text is adjusted according to the screen width, not sure why could that be misleading... specifically when i say - "visible on the screen within that div"